# How can I remove duplicates from a spinner in android

Tags: java, android, spinner, android-spinner

The code for the spinner is below, The spinners on my app tend to duplicate it's content sometimes for some weird reason. How do I prevent this from happening?:

```
Spinner spinnerG = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spGroup);
    final ArrayAdapter<String> dataAdapterG = new ArrayAdapter<>
            (this, R.layout.simple_spinner_item, groups);
    dataAdapterG.setDropDownViewResource(R.layout.support_simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    spinnerG.setAdapter(dataAdapterG);                                   //general basics       //sets up the group spinner, filled with the groups list

    spinnerG.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id)
        {
            selectedGroup = groups.get(position);
            studentsToShow.clear();
            for(int i = 0; i < studList.size(); i++){
                if(studList.get(i).getGroup().equals(selectedGroup)){
                    Students a = new Students();
                    a.setFirstName(studList.get(i).getFirstName());
                    a.setLastName(studList.get(i).getLastName());
                    a.setStudentID(studList.get(i).getStudentID());
                    a.setGroup(studList.get(i).getGroup());
                    studentsToShow.add(a);                                                      //when a new group is chosen the list of students in the selected group needs to be updated
                }                                                                               //this re uses the code earlier to make a list of student in the selected group
            }
            updateSpS();                                                                        //updates the student spinner
        }
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent){
        }
    });
```

Comment: on which Activity/Fragment lifecycle callback did you set this `Spinner`?

Comment: Do these before update the Spinner:
1- Create                     -> HashSet<Students>  hashSet=new HashSet<>();
2- Add all the items to the hashSet  -> hashSet.addAll(studentsToShow);
3- Clear the list ->                                  studentsToShow.clear();
4- Add the hashSet to the List      ->   studentsToShow.addAll(hashSet);
5- Call spinnerAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

Answer (score 0):

The spinner will duplicate if you have put this `oncreate` event. Put the spinner population code on the `onResume` method.

Answer (score 0):

From the snippet shared with the question, its hard to guess why OP would have duplicate value. An educated guess is his onItemSelected() is being called multiple times.

Spinner's (in my personal view, is one of the worst android widget) `onItemSelected()` can be called multiple times for different reasons, one of the thing I would recommend to try this way -

```
class SpinnerInteractionListener implements AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener, View.OnTouchListener {

        boolean userSelect = false;

        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            userSelect = true;
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int pos, long id) {
            if (userSelect) {
                // Your selection handling code here
                userSelect = false;
                if(view!=null){
                    selectedGroup = groups.get(position);
                    studentsToShow.clear();
                    for(int i = 0; i < studList.size(); i++){
                        if(studList.get(i).getGroup().equals(selectedGroup)){
                            Students a = new Students();
                            a.setFirstName(studList.get(i).getFirstName());
                            a.setLastName(studList.get(i).getLastName());
                            a.setStudentID(studList.get(i).getStudentID());
                            a.setGroup(studList.get(i).getGroup());
                            studentsToShow.add(a);                                                      //when a new group is chosen the list of students in the selected group needs to be updated
                        }                                                                               //this re uses the code earlier to make a list of student in the selected group
                    }
                    updateSpS();                                                                        //updates the student spinner
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

And then set -

```
SpinnerInteractionListener listener = new SpinnerInteractionListener();
spinnerG.setOnTouchListener(listener);
spinnerG.setOnItemSelectedListener(listener);
```

This at the same time takes care unwanted callbacks of onItemSelected() without user touch and if any previous leaked listeners.

Comment: Yeah, I have 3 spinners in one activity, if that helps the question, all duplicate after repeatedly opening the spinner

Comment: Did it help? @victor?

Comment: you are populating studentsToShow in each of those?

Comment: Hey Amit, I'll try it and let you know